# cypress assertion in page object file

Tags: cypress

I am trying place the assertion function in Page object file to avoid multiple .should in my script file, below is my code:

```
            Elements.flow.getheader().should('have.text', 'Confirm Funding Summary')
            Elements.flow.getblueinfotext().should('have.text', 'Warning')
            Elements.flow.getvelocitytext().should('have.text','Velocity')
            Elements.flow.getheading1().should('have.text', 'Complete')
            Elements.flow.getheading2().should('have.text', 'Learn ')
            Elements.flow.getheading3().should('have.text', 'Introduce')
            Elements.flow.getheading4().should('have.text', 'Verified')
```

How can I get the element/web locator in my function dynamically to assert the text

```
validateText(expectedText) {
 dynamicelement.should('have.text','expectedText')
})
```

Comment: That sounds a bit more complicated to maintain. Have you considered extracting all the headings and then asserting against an array of the expected heading text?

Comment: yes, but they are on different pages